# How to perform looping in laravel search controller?

Tags: laravel

In a search controller of Laravel, I am trying to split a string '$travelIdea->tags' into an array '$listtags', and then perform searching to each $listtags[$i], but failed to do so (in "Else" part of if($scope == 'Destination')).

I know that what I should do is similar to a for-loop.

Could anyone give me some suggestion on this?

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $search = $request->get('search');
    $partialsearch = $request->get('partialsearch');
    $scope = $request->get('scope');

    if($scope == 'Destination'){    
        if($partialsearch)
        $travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('destination','LIKE','%'.$search."%")->get();
            else $travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('destination','%'.$search."%")->get();
    }

        else {
            $listtags = explode(',', $travelIdea->tags);
            $foreach($i as $i){
                if($partialsearch)
                    $travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('listtags[$i]','LIKE','%'.$search."%")->get(); 
                    else $travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('listtags[$i]','%'.$search."%")->get();  
                    return view('travelIdea.search', compact('travelIdea'));
            });
        }


}
```

Comment: `$foreach($i as $i)` might be the problem I think at the first glance

Comment: Where do you get the `$travelIdea` value you are trying to explode? As @senty pointed out, that foreach would be a problem, you should instead iterate over `$listtags`.

Comment: Another missing point is where are you going to use `$travelIdea` if you are entering the first if statement. As no view would be rendered

Comment: @mdexp and senty, thanks for your reply and I understand what the problem is. Actually I would like to do something similar to my first part (i.e. '$travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('tags','LIKE','%'.$search."%")->get(); '$travelIdea=TravelIdea::where('tags','%'.$search."%")->get();), but 'tags' is a DB field containing 'tag1,tag2,tag3,...,tag n', and I need to perform the searching with each tag. That makes me confused how to do that in the search controller...